# How can I install urxvt terminal on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, rxvt

How I can install the urxvt terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt install rxvt-unicode
```

Make sure you have the universe repository enabled.

Link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rxvt-unicode